# Campo único en MySQL

Tags: mysql

estoy tratando de alterar un campo de mi tabla usuarios para que sea único y así desde mi aplicación Android no se puedan ingresar dos registros con el mismo valor, revisando unas cuantas paginas se supone que lo que quiero lo lograria con agregar la siguiente linea:

```
alter table usuarios add unique (login_usuario);
```

sin embargo recibo el siguiente error:

> Columna BLOB column usada en especificación de clave sin tamaño de la clave

Este seria el código de la creación de mi tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
`id_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT,
`login_usuario` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 
'telefono',
`nombre_usuario` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`password_usuarios` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`password_repeat_usuario` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`email_usuario` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`nacimiento_usuario` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`sexo_usuario` text CHARACTER SET utf32 COLLATE utf32_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`id_cliente` int(11) NOT NULL,
`edad_usuario` int(100) NOT NULL,
`id_cargo` int(11) NOT NULL,
`estado_usuario` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`dui_usuario` int(9) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
`meses_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL) 
ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

No encontré mucho al respecto sobre que es lo que ocasiona el error, de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Una pregunta: es un error de tipeo cometido al hacer tu pregunta el no poner la coma luego de COMMENT? o es así tu código?

Comment: Si asi es el codigo nunca he tenia problemas en ese punto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mí me funcionó así como el código debajo, es una cuestión de sintaxis, el comentario telefono lo coloqué en la misma línea, pues lo tomaba por defecto como un dato BLOB, por eso el error. Fíjate también si tu server admite AUTO_INCREMENT o AUTO INCREMENT.

```
CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
`id_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
`login_usuario` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'telefono',
`nombre_usuario` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`password_usuarios` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`password_repeat_usuario` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`email_usuario` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`nacimiento_usuario` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`sexo_usuario` text CHARACTER SET utf32 COLLATE utf32_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`id_cliente` int(11) NOT NULL,
`edad_usuario` int(100) NOT NULL,
`id_cargo` int(11) NOT NULL,
`estado_usuario` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`dui_usuario` int(9) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
`meses_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL) 
ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Comment: Excelente era error de sintaxis muchas gracias!